# Root can use Git, but any other account: -bash: git: command not found

Tags: git, bash

.bashrc (on user account):

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH
```

How can I get Git to work on accounts other than Root?

Comment: Why would you explicitly add `/usr/bin` to `$PATH`?  It should already be there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `root`, do `which git`:

```
[ 08:45 root@host ~ ]# which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

then take the path that is returned (`/usr/local/bin/git`, or whatever) and add it (except for the last `/git` part) to that line of the users `.bashrc` like so:

```
[ 08:45 jon@host ~ ]$ vi ~/.bashrc

export PATH=/usr/bin:$PATH:/usr/local/bin
```

Then `source` the `.bashrc` file:

```
[ 08:45 jon@host ~ ]$ source ~/.bashrc
```

Also, make sure the file is executable by all (not just `root`) with `chmod 755` so it looks like this:

```
[ 08:45 jon@host ~ ]$ sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/git
[ 08:45 jon@host ~ ]$ ls -l /usr/local/bin/git
-rwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  root   613B Jan 12 15:26 git
```

Comment: I figured it out prior to reading this, but you would've lead me to the answer!

Answer (score -1):

My problem was solved by making this entry in my deploy.rb file:
    set :local_scm_command, :default

Please see the entry in this link:
https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-From-The-Beginning

"A quick aside: you might have subversion (or whatever SCM you’re using) installed, but in a place that’s not in the standard path. (The standard path is typically /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin.) If this is the case, Capistrano won’t be able to find your svn executable, and you’ll need to tell Capistrano explicitly where it is. To do so, set :scm_command to the path on the remote servers where it is located. If you do this, though, you might discover that Capistrano can no longer find the command on the local server; in that case, set :local_scm_command to :default (or to the explicit path on your local server)."

Comment: Downvoting because the OP never mentioned anything about Ruby; in fact, he was very clear that he was referring to the bash shell.